# ls: cannot access '/usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6': No such file or directory

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, terminal, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to install opencv following the tutorial - 
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/

I got through till 'make -j4' and made 100% compile.

After this step, when I try ls /usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6, I get the following error - 
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6': No such file or directory

cd /usr/local/python/cv2
ls -l

total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   98 Jul  3 13:55 config.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2857 Nov 17  2018 **init**.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  151 Nov 17  2018 load_config_py2.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  262 Nov 17  2018 load_config_py3.py

which python
/home/ciaran/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python

I have looked at multiple forums online and tried troubleshooting but I still can't get past this step.

Comment: Can you run `echo $PATH` and `echo $PYTHONPATH` in your terminal and paste the results please?

Comment: echo $PATH
> /home/ciaran/.virtualenvs/cv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

echo $PYTHONPATH
>

Comment: The problem is that the python-3.6 folder does not exist where you are trying to call it. Can you run `which python` and add an edit for the results?

Comment: /home/ciaran/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python

Comment: Try running `ls /home/ciaran/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python` and see what you get.

Comment: /home/ciaran/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python

Comment: ls /home/ciaran/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python  /home/ciaran/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python

Comment: So it looks like your virtual environment got deleted at some point. I'm not too sure on where it went though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.

"If your compile chokes and hangs, it may be due to a threading race condition. In the event you run into this problem, simply delete your build  directory, recreate it, and re-run cmake  and make . This time do not include the flag next to make."

Used $ make in place of $ make -j4 in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The error is appearing because python is not set in your path, so your system doesn't know where python is. Run the below command in your terminal and it should fix it:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"
```

Comment: Thanks Evan! I tried it and its still the same. 
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6': No such file or directory  
  ls /usr/local/python/cv2/  
  config.py  __init__.py  load_config_py2.py  load_config_py3.py

Comment: echo $PATH  
/home/ciaran/.virtualenvs/cv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/bin/python:/usr/local/bin/python

Comment: Ahhhh, I think I know what's happening. When you run this part `mkvirtualenv cv -p python3` are you activating the virtual environment you are creating?

Comment: The instruction asks for the virtualenv cv to be activated after that line.

Comment: To this point '$ pkg-config --modversion opencv' everything works exactly as per instructions in the page - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/ .. After this, when I try ls /usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6 , I get the error

Comment: Can run `cd /usr/local/python/cv2` and then `ls -l` in your terminal and past the results?

Comment: total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   98 Jul  3 13:55 config.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2857 Nov 17  2018 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  151 Nov 17  2018 load_config_py2.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  262 Nov 17  2018 load_config_py3.py

Comment: Haha sorry, please edit your question with the response. I don't think it'll fit in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue with Python 3.6, managed to find the file using the search tool in the GUI.

Mine is in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python-3.6/
```

Named `cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so`

Then it worked corrrectly